# Edit HyperLink NavigationURI WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, navigateuri

I'm new to WPF.
I have a `ComboBox` with multiple values and a `HyperLink`, whenever the `ComboBox` value changes, I want to change the `NavigateUri` of the `HyperLink` accordingly.

In the cs file, I have a dictionary, where the keys are the same as the combo items, and the value of each key is the link I want to navigate to according to the `ComboBox` selection.

```
 LinkQuery["A"] = "https://google.com";
 LinkQuery["B"] = "https://facebook.com";
 LinkQuery["C"] = "https://Youtube.com";

<ComboBox x:Name="box_ComboBox"  Visibility="Visible"  Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="4" Width="90"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Fields}"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Field}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="component_ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>

....

<TextBlock x:Name="LinkToQuery" Grid.Row="39" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="10">           
            <Hyperlink x:Name="URLQuery" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate" Foreground="Blue">
                Selected: A
            </Hyperlink>
 </TextBlock>
```

And the cs file:

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

private void component_ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedComponent = box_ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        LinkToQuery.Text = string.Format("Selected: {0} ", box_ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
        URLQuery.NavigateUri = new System.Uri(LinkQuery[selectedComponent],System.UriKind.Absolute);

    }
```

When I change the Combo selection, the text does change properly, but the link does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: LinkQuery is a Dictionary<string,string>, and Fields is a CollectionView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `Run` element inside the `Hyperlink` and set the `Text` property of this one:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="LinkToQuery" Grid.Row="39" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="10">           
    <Hyperlink x:Name="URLQuery" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate" Foreground="Blue">
        <Run x:Name="linkText" Text="Selected: A" />
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

---

```
private void component_ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedComponent = box_ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    linkText.Text = string.Format("Selected: {0} ", selectedComponent);
    URLQuery.NavigateUri = new System.Uri(LinkQuery[selectedComponent], System.UriKind.Absolute);
}
```

Comment: Works Great! Thank you so much.
Can you please give me a brief explanation about the Run element and what change it has made?

Comment: When you set the Text property of LinkToQuery, you are clearing out the Hyperlink.